# how to handle socket errors as exceptions in python + paramiko?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, paramiko

I want to return an error code when the following error gets raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "UserManagementRemote.py", line 202, in create_group
  ssh.connect(hostname, username=user, password=remotepass)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 290, in connect
   sock.connect(addr)
 File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
>>>
```

But I'm currently having trouble catching the error raised.

```
try:
   ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
   ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   ssh.connect(hostname, username=user, password=remotepass)
except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
   return 259
except socket.error:
   return 261
chan = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
chan.exec_command(command)
codest = chan.recv_exit_status()
ssh.close()
return codest
```

Resulting on this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "UserManagementRemote.py", line 207, in create_group
  except socket.error:
NameError: global name 'socket' is not defined
>>>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you imported the socket module?

Comment: I thought I didn't need to import any additional modules because when there's no exception the code functions as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do

```
import socket
```

in the module where you do the exception handling.

To prevent this problem in the future, run [pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) on all your source files. That will catch a lot of other errors as well.

Comment: Thanks, because it never complained until I did hit the exception I thought I had everything I needed already imported.